# C# Winforms - Trying to display OpenFileDialog by adding FileDialogPermission to AppDomainSetup

Tags: c#, winforms, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I'm trying understand Sandboxing in .Net4.0 but stumbled over this problem and unsure how to get around it within a C# Windows Form application.

Within solution explorer I have 2 projects. The first project simply contains a Winform with a single button on it. When I click the button, the code is meant to call the second project and open up an `OpenFileDialog` control. I'm not doing any file reads at all..just trying to simple display of the `OpenFileDialog` control.
I am running under administrator priveleges but still receiving the following error message:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Help would be appreciated, here's the actual code:

```
 //Project 1:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace DeleteSandboxing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //STEP1 - Setup the "PermissionSet"
            PermissionSet permSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);



            permSet.AddPermission(newSecurityPermission
            (SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

            permSet.AddPermission(new UIPermission(UIPermissionWindow.AllWindows));
            permSet.AddPermission(new  
            FileDialogPermission(FileDialogPermissionAccess.Open));

            //STEP2 - Setup the "AppDomainSetup"
            AppDomainSetup objSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
            objSetup.ApplicationBase =    
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase;

            //STEP3 - Create the "AppDomain"
            AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain name", 
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence, objSetup, permSet);


            //STEP4 - Call "ShowDialog()" via the interface i1.
            Interface1 i1 =
            (ClassLibrary1.Class1)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("ClassLibrary1",  
            "ClassLibrary1.Class1");

            i1.ShowDialog();

        }
    }
}


//Project 2:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Reflection;


namespace ClassLibrary1
{

    public class Class1:MarshalByRefObject,Interface1
    {
        public void ShowDialog()
        {
            OpenFileDialog obj = new OpenFileDialog();
            obj.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public interface Interface1
    {
        void ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you added permissions for the `OpenFileDialog` but you didn't assign any `FileIOPermission` so by nature the dialog wants some file access permissions.  You can assign this permnission to your `PermissionSet` object a couple different ways:

If you want unrestricted file open access within your `OpenFileDialog`:

```
    permSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

If you want to give only file open access to a specified path(s):

```
    permSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, "path_name"));
```

With this type of permission you would also need to set the default directory of the `OpenFileDialog`;

```
    OpenFileDialog obj = new OpenFileDialog();
    obj.InitialDirectory = "path_name_defined_in_permissions";
    obj.ShowDialog();
```

You may also need to change the assembly name in "Step 4" to reflect the file extension:

```
         Interface1 i1 =
        (ClassLibrary1.Class1)domain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap("ClassLibrary1.dll",
        "ClassLibrary1.Class1");
```

I needed to make this change to get mine working, but that just may be due to the fact that I'm using a network folder for my development path.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for going the extra mile and telling me about the open access for a specified path also. Your a champion!

Comment: Very glad it worked for you!  Please mark my answer as The Answer =)